# Generating objects randomly from prefabs in Unity2D

Tags: c#, 2d, random, unity

I am developing an infinite runner using Unity. I have already figured out how to loop a set of backgrounds randomly but I am having problems doing the same for the objects.

So, I have a few objects or obstacles in my prefabs. I want them to generate randomly in the game, not everything at once though.

How do I do that? Can I please get a well-explained piece of code for the purpose?

EDIT : I want the objects to be destroyed as soon as they move out of camera's view (The cam which is following the player).

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is how to select a random object from a collection of objects ? Add the objects in a list, calculate a random int (the index) from 0 to list.size - 1 and select the item with that index.

Comment: A little more precision would be appreciated. I am just a beginner. Also, I want the objects generated to be in contact with the floor.

Comment: I don't have experience with unity to help you with the exact code. But if you are trying to select a random `object` from a `list of objects`. You can simply  generate a `randomInt` from 0 to list.size - 1 and get the random object from `list.getAtIndex(randomInt)`

Comment: @Shiro Hmm, true. But I think it's not the best way to so it, additionally, I want that particular object to be destroyed after it gets out of view. Thanks though ;thumbsup;

Comment: It is the only way to do it. If your concern is about pre-creating those objects, you could have just a `list of strings` with the path to the `prefabs` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Load an array with all your prefabs (In the examples the prefabs are all into the same folder)

```
public List<GameObject> items;     
void Start()
     {
         // If you store all your items that you want to load in the same folder (Assets/Resources/MyItemsToLoad).
         items = Resources.LoadAll("MyItemsToLoad") as GameObject[];
     }
```

When you need to random instantiate them

```
...
    int prefabIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,items.Count-1);
        Instantiate(items[prefabIndex], _position, _rotation);
...
```

Then put an empty gameobject with a "isTrigger" collider past camera view (i think you can make it child of camera):

[image]

Each obstacle object needs a script attached like this

```
 void OnCollisionEnter( Collision collision ) {

         if( collision.trasform.tag = 'DestroyTriggerCollider' ) {
         Destroy(gameObject);
         }
     }
```